# Integrating a flash component on Joomla without reloading it on each page

Tags: javascript, html, flash, joomla, joomla-extensions

Is-there a joomla compenent that permits to integrate a flash SWF on a joomla website : without realoding it for each page (by using an IFRAME or anything else

Answer (score 0):

Hello anonymous (nice name!)

This would not be ideal at all, since if you were to have the flash content in an iframe, it would mean that EVERY other content loaded by joomla would need to be loaded into separate iframes in order to prevent the entire document from reloading.

This is impossible (well, ALMOST) due to the nature of the joomla core and how it is constructed at run time.

So many people (clients) request this feature of flash not reloading on each new page. It is the nature of the web and XHTML (or any front end web languages) that in order for new content to be display the document must be reloaded. Yes there are asynchronous methods such as AJAX etc, but those are out of the question for Joomla, unless you spent light years hacking away at the core.

If you had simple "views" or different objects you wanted to show within your flash movie and not have the ENTIRE movie start from frame 1 (for example) you could append URL variables to the flash source, and then based on what those variables are, you could manipulate what content is shown in the flash movie.

The swf file will still reload (it has to if the document is reloading) but at least you can serve up different content within the SWF file.

I hope this steers you in the right direction.

Kind regards,
Simon

Comment: In fact the flash contains a live Netstream Audio/Video communication : this is why I don't want to reload the flash SWF as it will (at least temporarely) interrupt the communication.

Comment: Fair enough. But unfortunately there is not workaround for this, it is the pure nature of the web. The best I can suggest. If the stream was not LIVE I'd suggest getting the current playhead time and simply seeking to that point on reload, but if it's live it's a different story. Sorry I cannot be of much help on this one.